# Table rows going to next page when pdf file is created

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have to create a pdf file with a header table and order table in my website, and have created it using ItextSharp library, the problem is that when I have one row in the table the pdf is created fine, buth when there are two or more rows whole order table is shifted to the next page.
Here is the code

```
    public virtual void PrintDeliverySheetsToPdf(Stream stream, IList<Order> orders, int languageId = 0, int vendorId = 0)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");

        if (orders == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("orders");

        var pageSize = PageSize.A4.Rotate();

        if (_pdfSettings.LetterPageSizeEnabled)
        {
            pageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
        }


        var doc = new Document(pageSize);
        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
        doc.Open();

        //fonts
        var titleFont = GetFont();
        titleFont.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        titleFont.Color = BaseColor.BLACK;
        var font = GetFont();
        var attributesFont = GetFont();
        attributesFont.SetStyle(Font.ITALIC);

        int ordCount = orders.Count;
        int ordNum = 0;
        //by default _pdfSettings contains settings for the current active store
        //and we need PdfSettings for the store which was used to place an order
        //so let's load it based on a store of the current order
        //var pdfSettingsByStore = _settingContext.LoadSetting<PdfSettings>(order.StoreId);


        var lang = _languageService.GetLanguageById(0);
        if (lang == null || !lang.Published)
            lang = _workContext.WorkingLanguage;
        #region Header

        //logo
        var logoPicture = _pictureService.GetPictureById(_pdfSettings.LogoPictureId);
        var logoExists = logoPicture != null;

        //header
        var headerTable = new PdfPTable(logoExists ? 3 : 2);
        headerTable.RunDirection = GetDirection(lang);
        headerTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

        var cellHeader1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.Station"), font)));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.RiderCode"), font)));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.RiderName"), font)));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.RiderSign"), font)));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        cellHeader1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        headerTable.AddCell(cellHeader1);

        var cellHeader2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.DateTime"), font)));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.DeliveryRoute"))));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.TimeSlot"))));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader2.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        cellHeader2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        cellHeader2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

        headerTable.AddCell(cellHeader2);

        if (logoExists)
            if (lang.Rtl)
                headerTable.SetWidths(new[] { 0.2f, 0.8f });
        //else
        //    headerTable.SetWidths(new[] { 0.8f, 0.2f });
        headerTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;

        //logo               
        if (logoExists)
        {
            var logoFilePath = _pictureService.GetThumbLocalPath(logoPicture, 0, false);
            var logo = Image.GetInstance(logoFilePath);
            logo.Alignment = GetAlignment(lang, true);
            logo.ScaleToFit(65f, 65f);

            var cellLogo = new PdfPCell();
            cellLogo.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            cellLogo.AddElement(logo);
            headerTable.AddCell(cellLogo);
        }
        headerTable.SplitLate = false;
        doc.Add(headerTable);


        var ordersTable = new PdfPTable(12);
        ordersTable.RunDirection = GetDirection(lang);
        ordersTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;
        ordersTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;

        ordersTable.SetWidths(new[] { 6, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 6, 13, 7 });


        //delivery Number
        var cellDeliveryNo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.DeliveryNo", lang.Id), font));
        cellDeliveryNo.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        cellDeliveryNo.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(cellDeliveryNo);


        //order Number
        var orderNo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.OrderNo", lang.Id), font));
        orderNo.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        orderNo.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(orderNo);

        //CN
        var cn = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.CN", lang.Id), font));
        cn.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        cn.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(cn);

        //Shipper Name
        var shipperName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.ShipperName", lang.Id), font));
        shipperName.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        shipperName.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(shipperName);

        //Shipper Address 
        var shipperAddress = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.ShipperAddress", lang.Id), font));
        shipperAddress.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        shipperAddress.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(shipperAddress);

        //Consignee Name
        var consigneeName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.ConsigneeName", lang.Id), font));
        consigneeName.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        consigneeName.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(consigneeName);

        //Consignee Address
        var consigneeAddress = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.ConsigneeAddress", lang.Id), font));
        consigneeAddress.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        consigneeAddress.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(consigneeAddress);

        //orderItems
        var orderItemsCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.OrderItems", lang.Id), font));
        orderItemsCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        orderItemsCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(orderItemsCell);

        //VAS
        var vas = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.VAS", lang.Id), font));
        vas.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        vas.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(vas);

        //DateTime
        var dateTime = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.DateTime", lang.Id), font));
        dateTime.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        dateTime.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(dateTime);

        //Remarks
        var remarks = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.Remarks", lang.Id), font));
        remarks.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        remarks.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(remarks);

        //Recievings
        var recievings = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("DeliverySheet.Receiving", lang.Id), font));
        recievings.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        recievings.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ordersTable.AddCell(recievings);

        #endregion

        foreach (var order in orders)
        {

            //Delivery No
            ordersTable.AddCell("");

            //Order Id
            ordersTable.AddCell(order.Id.ToString());

            //Order CN
            ordersTable.AddCell(order.CN == null ? "" : order.CN.ToString());

            //Billing Name
            ordersTable.AddCell(order.BillingAddress.FirstName + " " + order.BillingAddress.LastName);

            //Billing Address
            ordersTable.AddCell(order.BillingAddress.Address1 + " " + order.BillingAddress.LandMark1 + " " + order.BillingAddress.LandMark2 + " " + order.BillingAddress.StateProvince.Name);

            //Consignee Name
            ordersTable.AddCell(order.ShippingAddress.FirstName + " " + order.ShippingAddress.LastName);

            //Consignee Address
            ordersTable.AddCell(order.ShippingAddress.Address1 + " " + order.ShippingAddress.LandMark1 + " " + order.ShippingAddress.LandMark2 + " " + order.ShippingAddress.StateProvince.Name);

            var orderItemProductCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase());
            foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)
            {

                orderItemProductCell.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(orderItem.Product.Name + " - " + orderItem.Product.Sku + "  Qty: " + orderItem.Quantity, font));
                orderItemProductCell.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
            }
            ordersTable.AddCell(orderItemProductCell);

            var vasCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase());
            foreach (var vasName in order.OrderValueAddedServices)
            {
                if (vasName.ValueAddedService != null)
                {
                    vasCell.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(vasName.ValueAddedService.Name, font));
                    vasCell.Phrase.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
                }
            }
            ordersTable.AddCell(vasCell);

            //Date Time Cell
            ordersTable.AddCell("");

            //Remarks Cell
            ordersTable.AddCell("");

            //Receiving Cell
            ordersTable.AddCell("");


            ordNum++;
            if (ordNum < ordCount)
            {
                doc.NewPage();
            }
        }
        ordersTable.SplitLate = false;
        doc.Add(ordersTable);
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Comment: (1.) you are using an old version of iText; the current version is [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). You should upgrade as the version you are using is no longer supported. Talk to your employer about this. (2.) Tables split automatically if they don't fit the page. Hence you are reporting normal behavior. Upgrade to iText 7 and we'll guide you on how to meet your requirement.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks, I will update it, then will edit the question.